# Angular 1.5 Material speed dial reserving space in table

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, floating-action-button

In Angular 1.5 Material I'm using an `<md-fab-speed-dial>` in a table's row header.

```
<tr>
  <th>Foobar
    <md-fab-speed-dial class="md-scale" md-direction="up">
      <md-fab-trigger>
        <md-button class="md-fab md-mini" aria-label="Menu">
          <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
        </md-button>
      </md-fab-trigger>
      <md-fab-actions>
        <md-button aria-label="Comment" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini">
          <md-icon>comment</md-icon>
        </md-button>
```

But the speed dial seems to be reserving space in the table for the FAB buttons! In other words, there is a huge gaping vertical space between "Foobar" and the speed dial trigger. Obviously this defeats the purpose of a triggered speed dial --- if I have to have all that space reserved, I might as well have just listed the FABs without a speed dial.

How do I prevent the speed dial from reserving space in a table for the triggered items? I only want space reserved for the trigger itself.

Comment: In the [Demo](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/fabSpeedDial) section "More options" - is this how you want it to be? Then just use `position: absolute` and position your button relative to the table

Comment: I want it to appear in a table cell, without reserving extra space above it. In other words, when it is closed, I don't want it to take up any more space than if the trigger were a single button. I want one of these in each cell in the column.

Comment: Add `position: relative` to the table cell and `position: absolute` to the speed dial. Set sufficient width and height on cell and position your speed dial using top/bottom and left/right css properties. If I still didn't get what you want, then could you please create a demo jsfiddle or plnkr so we could experiment with it?

Comment: I don't understand why it should be complicated. I don't understand why I should fiddle with positioning. If I put the letter "X" in a cell, it takes up the space of a letter "X". If I put a normal FAB in a cell, it takes up the space of a FAB. If I put a FAB speed dial, it should take up the space of the FAB trigger. Do you need to muck with `position` for a FAB that simply appears in the character flow? No. Why should I have do any differently for a FAB speed dial?

Answer (score 4):

This concrete implementation of the fab button is made around the flex display and reserves the space needed for the actions present inside the md-fab-actions tag, so it's relying solely on that you'll position it on it's own "layer" (i.e. absolutely or fixed on the screen).

I understand your fustration about the component itself, but that's the way it works... You can look for another component or "tweak" it to use as you need. The tweak is not so hard, and it's not as complicated as Ilia Luzyanin indicates on his comments... you just have to add this style to the md-fab-actions tag:

```
<md-fab-actions style="position: absolute; bottom: -156px;">
```

and you're done. Take into account that you'll have to manually set the bottom property to minus the size of the buttons that are inside of it, that is 52px for each one. Here you have a working CodePen with three fabs with 2, 3 and 4 actions inside a table row: [Examle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/apBmKQ)

If you want it to open upwards you'll have to replace the "bottom" property for a "top" one, because the action buttons are initially hidden behind the button that triggers them, and their position is relative to it.

Comment: Good answer, but note the example link is broken.

Comment: upps sorry! Did'nt notice that. Thanks